# Parallax Background resizing

Tags: c#, xna, parallax

I'm attempting my first 2D updown scroller really, and i can't seem to get the background size to fully work. for whatever reason it stays small and it is of no help.
I think in the beginning of  the parallax scrolling class i was told to initialize variables and I know which one I have to change.

```
public Texture2D picture; 
        public Vector2 position = Vector2.Zero; 
        public Vector2 offset = Vector2.Zero; 
        public float depth = 0.0f; 
        public float moveRate = 0.0f; 
        public Vector2 pictureSize = Vector2.Zero; 
        public Color color = Color.White;
```

I believe i must change pictureSize in order to make it bigger as the current sizing i get this!

[image]

The final question i have is, How can I remove the whitespace from the ship image?
Thanks!
If any more code is needed please tell me, the reason I did not put it there, is due to the length.

EDIT*:
Here is the code for the rendering of the actual ship

```
public void Render(SpriteBatch batch)
{
    batch.Begin();
    batch.Draw(shipSprite, position, null, Color.White, 0.0f, spriteOrigin, 1.0f,
    SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
    batch.End();
}
```

The whitespace seems to be provided by XNA as I've cleared it several times using photoshop.
Because i can't directly upload to the site I have put it here: http://www.justbeamit.com/nk95n
And for the background rendering its

```
public void Draw()        
{           
    layerList.Sort(CompareDepth);  
    batch.Begin();  
    for (int i = 0; i < layerList.Count; i++)       
    {
       if (!moveLeftRight)
       {
           if (layerList[i].position.Y < windowSize.Y)
           {
               batch.Draw(layerList[i].picture, new Vector2(0.0f,       
               layerList[i].position.Y), layerList[i].color);
           }
           if (layerList[i].position.Y > 0.0f)
               batch.Draw(layerList[i].picture, new Vector2(0.0f,   
               layerList[i].position.Y - layerList[i].pictureSize.Y),  
               layerList[i].color);
           else
               batch.Draw(layerList[i].picture, new Vector2(0.0f, 
               layerList[i].position.Y + layerList[i].pictureSize.Y), 
               layerList[i].color);
       }
       else
       {
           if (layerList[i].position.X < windowSize.X)
           {
               batch.Draw(layerList[i].picture, new Vector2(layerList[i].position.X,
               0.0f), layerList[i].color);
           }
           if (layerList[i].position.X > 0.0f)
               batch.Draw(layerList[i].picture, new Vector2(layerList[i].position.X - 
               layerList[i].pictureSize.X, 0.0f), layerList[i].color);
           else
               batch.Draw(layerList[i].picture, new Vector2(layerList[i].position.X + 
           layerList[i].pictureSize.X, 0.0f), layerList[i].color);
       }                
   }             
   batch.End();       
}
```

^
This is not my code but rather from a book I'm reading on how to do XNA(first attempt at C# to :/)

Comment: This might be better suited to gamedev.SE. I've flagged for a moderator to move this.

Comment: We need to see the relevant code and more details. Can your provide **(1.** Your code that renders the spaceship and background **(2.** The image of the spaceship (does it have whitespace in the image file or is it rendered that way?)

Comment: Edited the above to include source code for those 2 things. THankyou for the move aswell

Answer (score 0):

Without all the relevant code and details it is a bit hard to tell the problem, But I assume your scrolling code has a [`spriteBatch.Draw()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw.aspx) call simlar to this:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, Destination, Source, Color.White);
```

The`Destination` is probably equal too `new Rectangle(0,0,pictureSize.X,pictureSize.Y)`, I'm assume with no code shown that the `pictureSize` is the size of the picture (No really!), with the spritebatch Destination parameter, you can "stretch" your image to your viewport.

With this your PictureSize should be the size of your viewport

```
pictureSize = new Vector2(graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth,graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight);
```

You can also use the `Scale` parameter of the [`SpiteBatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.aspx) to enlarge it (However it will get blurred) or just create a bigger image for your needs.

Now for the spaceship having a white background, is XNA doing this or is the image white? I assume the latter, you will need a photo editing tool such as [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) to remove the white background of the image.

Comment: This was helpful until i found the .Draw() method. This code was taken from a book actually.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I remove the whitespace from the ship image?

You could try making white transparent, using the [Bitmap.MakeTransparent method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.drawing.bitmap.maketransparent%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Something like this might work:

```
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);            
        Bitmap test = new Bitmap("C:\Myimage.jpg");
        test.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
```

Comment: I can see this being very useful though where do i enter this code? Where would i put this in a xna template really?

Comment: You would need to convert your `Texture2D` to a `Bitmap`, this code isn't for XNA it looks like.

Comment: Oh that doesn't help :( Any suggestions? I'm stuck with this.